# iptables allow outgoing SSH and HTTPS traffic for established connections,

Tags: iptables, firewall

I have allowed outgoing TCP traffic from port 150 like this:

iptables -A INPUT -p udp  dport 161 -j ACCEPT

Now I want to allow outgoing SSH and HTTPS for established connection. How do I do that? I am new to iptables please help..

Comment: Your rule contradicts your first phrase: the rule allows UDP packets destined to the firewall port 161.

Answer (score 1):

The ports for SSH and HTTPS are by default 22 and 443. Assuming your interface name is eth0, you would need 2 rules such as:

```
  iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
  iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Thanks, is my iptables -A INPUT -p udp dport 161 -j ACCEPT right for allowing outgoing TCP traffic? or is it wrong? and shouldent there be --state ESTABLISHED in your code?